# EF4 ASP.NET - Managing Entity Edits between HTTP Posts and Rollback

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am struggling with the following use-case:

User amends an existing order. The order is complex - lots of related 'entities' (addresses, post options, suppliers, makes, models, various items etc). Across multiple http posts.

User wants to discard the changes.

--

I have an order entity and as the user is editing this I am making various changes to the entity associations e.g changing order.address, order.items.add(item)...

In a single post this is fine, but across posts I don't know how best store state. If I store the entities then I cannot save the changes as they are across different data contexts. I have read that it is bad practice to store the data context in the session state i.e. long-lived context. I can't save changes after each edit/post because I cannot roll-back (?). I really would like to work with the entities during the editing process rather than one big save at the end (taking UI settings and applying these in one chunk).

This must be a pretty common problem - it's driving me mad. Any help really appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using Self Tracking Entities? If so, you might be able to save them to the viewstate, that is if you know they won't get to big.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem where we are building a complex business object through a multi-page wizard.

Instead of creating a partially complete business object at each step of the wizard, we create a dedicated wizard object that looks pretty similar to the business object, populate that through the wizard. At each step in the wizard, the wizard object is saved into the database. At the end the user can accept it and it is converted to a real business object and then becomes visible to everyone else, or they can bin it and no-one else ever knows it existed.

If this kind of approach was not suitable, I suspect you're looking at some kind of difference tracking, either at the entity or database levels. Neither are simple to implement, work with or manage in a system. The former would be some kind of calculation and storage of *n* changes to the entities and developing an algorithm to undo them, the latter depends on your RDBMS, but might include versioned rows or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its pretty much common for us. In most scenarios we use the MVC approach. Even without the actual ASP .NET MVC Projects, we use similar ViewModel with our Views/Pages/Scenarios etc. where there is no direct/single entity mapping to the Business Layer (in other words, Business.Entities). This is pretty much similar to DTOs.

It is always easy to use Disconnected EF. We retrieve data and discard the context, then transform the Entities into ViewModels/DTOs if necessary. When you need to persist changes, all you have to do is to create a new context, find the latest entity instance do the changes.

The Views/Pages/Controllers will be managing these ViewModels/DTOs. Tracking Changed and Deleted content can be done by introducing a `HistoryList<T>` (you can extend a `List<T>` to implement this).

Once done, using a Controller/Workflow/Component you can observe the ViewModel/DTO and do the necessary changes to your Entities using a new Context to retrieve and persist.

It involves a bit of a coding and I would say its not a perfect solution since it has its own pros and cons.

/KP